# RailsでUnicornを起動しようとするとエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws, unicorn, capistrano

#### 前提・実現したいこと

AWSのec2-userでデプロイを行いたいです。
以前はできていたのですが、突然デプロイができなくなってしまいました。
デプロイができるようにしたいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

ターミナル画面でのエラーです。

```
$ RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=1 unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
Traceback (most recent call last):
    10: from /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<main>'
     9: from /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
     8: from /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `new'
     6: from /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:77:in `initialize'
     5: from /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:77:in `new'
     4: from /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:77:in `initialize'
     3: from /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:84:in `reload'
     2: from /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:84:in `instance_eval'
     1: from config/unicorn.rb:5:in `reload'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:592:in `working_directory': config_file=config/unicorn.rb would not be accessible in working_directory=/var/www/current (ArgumentError)
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

#### Users/kanexxshxx/projects_2020/post_app/config/ unicorn.rbに記述してあるコード

```
app_path = File.expand_path('../../../', __FILE__)

worker_processes 1

working_directory "#{app_path}/current"

listen "#{app_path}/shared/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock"
pid "#{app_path}/shared/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{app_path}/shared/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{app_path}/shared/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

timeout 60
```

#### GEMFILEに記述しているコード要約

```
ruby '2.5.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.4', '>= 5.2.4.2'
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano3-unicorn'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'brakeman', require: false
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

group :production do
  gem 'unicorn', '5.4.1'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'devise'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'devise-i18n'
```

#### 試したこと

ターミナル

```
$ sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /var/www/post_app/tmp
```

その後

```
 $ RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=1 unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
```

を実行しても同じエラー内容でした。

解決したいのでどうかよろしくお願いします。

Comment: `unicorn.rb`はどこに置かれているファイルですか？

Comment: @MasafumiOkura Users/kanexxshxx/projects_2020/post_app/config/unico.rb です！

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:592:in `working_directory': config_file=config/unicorn.rb would not be accessible in working_directory=/var/www/current (ArgumentError)
> master failed to start, check stderr log for details
> ```

とあるので、

1. /var/www/current が存在しているかどうかのチェック
2. そのディレクトリの書き込み権限のチェック
3. unicorn.rbに書いてあるworking_directoryの設定を見直されるといいかと思います。
   4.

> ```
> config_file=config/unicorn.rb
> ```

ともあるので、/var/www/current/config/unicorn.rbがあるか確認してください。

Comment: @cubick, @winty21s1 `[ec2-user post_app]$ ls`で確認したところcurrentは存在しました！書き込み権限は　`-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1280  5月 21 06:02 unicorn.rb`とあったのであるのかと思います。`unicorn.rb`の`working_directory "#{app_path}/current"`なのであってるのかと思うのですが、エラーになってしまいます、、、
`

Comment: 回答に4を追加しました。そちらもご確認ください。